# How to update XML file value based on Key value using java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to update xml file with system date in specific value based on key name,below is the sample xml file,here i want to update 10-25-2018 to present system date using java code,Please help me to achieve this.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="CommandTimeOut" value="7200"/>
    <!--<add key="Bill" value="0"/>-->
    <add key="Ism" value="1"/>
    <add key="Cule" value="en-US"/>
    <add key="Date" value="10-25-2018"/>
    <add key="CreatedUser" value="SCHEDULER"/>

    </appSettings>
```

Comment: Please show your code and explain the problem you have.

Comment: I don't have any java code..

Comment: Then sorry, but this site is for actual programming problems. You should better search for a tutorial and learn the basics first. You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this code For updating your xml file .

```
public class XML_Parser {

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("D:\\test.xml");

        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//appSettings/add[@key]");
        NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int c = 0; c < nl.getLength(); c++) {
            Node currentItem = nl.item(c);
            if (currentItem.getAttributes().getNamedItem("key").getNodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
                currentItem.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").setNodeValue(dateFormat.format(date));

            }

        }

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("D:\\test.xml"));
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please never catch Exception. Always try to catch as specific as possible.

Comment: Nitheesh,Thank kyou for your java code and i've resolved the issue with below link,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490437/how-to-change-edit-node-value-of-xml-which-have-an-attribute-with-key-and-value